# How to select all records and columns from salesforce using the query option in Azure data factory? (SELECT * FROM test ALL ROWS)

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory, soql

In Azure data factory I want to retrieve all possible data there is in a salesforce table. Also, the archived and the deleted records. I try to do the following but it won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM test ALL ROWS
```

I also want the archived and the deleted rows of the test object in salesforce.
[image]

```
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (120) SOQL_FIRST mode prepare failure:
SOQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'SELECT Id FROM test ALL ROWS<<< ??? >>>'.
SQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'SELECT Id FROM test ALL<<< ??? >>> ROWS'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (120) SOQL_FIRST mode prepare failure:
SOQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'SELECT Id FROM Event ALL ROWS<<< ??? >>>'.
SQL error: [Microsoft][SQLEngine] (31480) syntax error near 'SELECT Id FROM test ALL<<< ??? >>> ROWS'.,Source=Microsoft Salesforce ODBC Driver,'
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Account` will give you all columns you're allowed to see but will be capped at 2000 records. If you want to export more - you need to explicitly list the columns out, Salesforce doesn't support `*`.

`ALL ROWS` is just for apex, Salesforce's server-side language. Over API it should be just the `queryAll` call which you're already using. Try queryAll with `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE IsDeleted = true` and it should show you the records in the bin (if any)

Comment: Thanks! So the select all fields and also all records including archived and deleted records:

SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Account WHERE (IsDeleted = true or false) or  (isArchived = ture or false)  ?

Comment: queryAll used with `SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Account LIMIT 200` should be enough. There's some official info in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm. You don't need to filter by isDeleted unless you want. Normal query will return 0 rows on `select id from account where isdeleted=true` because you need that queryAll to go to the Bin. I don't recall seeing `isArchived` field? Might be something used only on Task/Event?